# How do I create dynamic div height in CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/kSuS7/2/

It's possible to be done with CSS/jQuery if text in `.content` have a long word so the `.content` height set to 300px and if in short text just remove the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via CSS you can use `max-height` instead of height. But I'm not sure that it will work in IE 6,7 & maybe in 8 too.

So alternative safe way is to use Jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("#content p").html().length>573)
    {

        $("#content").height(300);
    }
});
```

See JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kSuS7/8/

Comment: Thanks @mesiesta for `max-height` + IE version

Answer (score 3):

Use `max-height` instead of `height`: http://jsfiddle.net/SRtJ2/

Note that *you can't have more than one element with the same id*. I changed `id="content"` to `class="content"` in both divs in your example.

For doing the same with jQuery as a workaround for browsers that don't support `max-height`:

```
$( function() {
    $.each( $( '.content' ), function() {
        if( $( this ).height() > 300) {
            $( this ).height( 300 );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: id changed to class. Thanks and it's working :). How about `max-height in` IE7?

Comment: @kampit Actually, now that I look at the other answers, none of the JS solutions actually work. I edited the answer with a working jQuery workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Set height to auto:

```
h2 {
font:18px/30px Arial;
}

.content {
width:200px;
height:auto;
overflow:auto;
margin-bottom:20px;
border:1px solid #000;
max-height: 300px;
}
```

You may want to set max-height as well, as really long content will extend out hugely.

Comment: Up-voted Juhana's as max-height alone does it. Beware of cross-browser compatibility though (max-height doesn't work in IE 6 and 7)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to have a trigger on the text size to set the height to 300px for "long" text.

Not tested

```
var txtSize = $("#content").val().length;

if(txtSize > 300){
  $("#content").height('300px');
}
```

Comment: Didn't see mesiesta answer, while i was writing.

Comment: value An integer representing the number of pixels, or an integer with an optional unit of measure appended (as a string).

Comment: Did you tested it? I guess val() will always get the value 0, because it's only take content of 'p' tag. You must use text() or html() instead of val().

Comment: No i didn't, i wrote in a hurry with a cut and paste from http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2, you are probably right and i did not see your post prior posting (no warnings about new answers while writing). My bad.